# DirectX11::HLSL::Как передать данные сразу в пиксельный шейдер?

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

В одном проекте на юнити, заметил, что там данные в шейдер передаются примерно таким образом:

```
    private void SetShaderParameters()
    {
        RayTracingShader.SetTexture(0, "_SkyboxTexture", SkyboxTexture);
        RayTracingShader.SetMatrix("_CameraToWorld", _camera.cameraToWorldMatrix);
        RayTracingShader.SetMatrix("_CameraInverseProjection", _camera.projectionMatrix.inverse);
        RayTracingShader.SetVector("_PixelOffset", new Vector2(Random.value, Random.value));
        RayTracingShader.SetFloat("_Seed", Random.value);

        Vector3 l = DirectionalLight.transform.forward;
        RayTracingShader.SetVector("_DirectionalLight", new Vector4(l.x, l.y, l.z, DirectionalLight.intensity));

        SetComputeBuffer("_Spheres", _sphereBuffer);
        SetComputeBuffer("_MeshObjects", _meshObjectBuffer);
        SetComputeBuffer("_Vertices", _vertexBuffer);
        SetComputeBuffer("_Indices", _indexBuffer);
    }
```

А в самом шейдере этими данными заполняются глобальные переменные:

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

RWTexture2D<float4> Result;

float4x4 _CameraToWorld;
float4x4 _CameraInverseProjection;

float4 _DirectionalLight;

float2 _PixelOffset;

Texture2D<float4> _SkyboxTexture;
SamplerState sampler_SkyboxTexture;

static const float PI = 3.14159265f;
static const float EPSILON = 1e-8;

float2 _Pixel;
float _Seed;
```

Возможно это работает потому что в том проекте использовался compute шейдер.
Но я думаю это применимо и к пиксельному шейдеры, а вопрос собственно в том, как это провернуть
в DirectX 11, без юнити.

Comment: А причем здесь с++?

Comment: Ну так я пишу на directX 11 c++. Хотя тут скорей hlsl, но c++ имеет место быть

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-resources-buffers-constant-how-to